# Pointers in Perl

Tags: perl

How to use pointer concepts in Perl? For example I have a line and want to search for the given string any where in the that line by positioning using the pointer. Kindly suggest me.

So I have 2 files with a key it like in 1st file I have data as in following columns with value in it as...

```
ID|Rating_Provider|Time|QualityRating z6Y1kWFT99|S&P_LONG|20110120 12:00:00 AM|NR z6Y1kWFT99|MOODY'S_LONG|20101101 12:00:00 AM|NR
```

and in 2nd file I have data as in following columns in it as...

```
ID|BBCMPSEC|QualityRating_S&P_LONG|Time_S&P_LONG|QualityRating_MOODY'S_LONG|Time_‌​MOODY'S_LONG
```

Now finally I need to see the data as...

```
ID|BBCMPSEC|QualityRating_S&P_LONG|Time_S&P_LONG|QualityRating_MOODY'S_LONG‌​|Time_MOODY'S_LONG z6Y1kWFT99|xxx|NR|20110120 12:00:00 AM.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ETA:** Based on your comments, I would say that you'd be best off using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV). Take a look at the documentation, it is quite helpful. Basically, you would do something like:

```
use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    binary     => 1,
    sep_char   => "|",
});
open my $fh, "<", "inputfile" or die $!;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    # @$row now contains your row data
}
```

---

Old answer

"pointers" are not used in perl. I assume you mean the position of the match. There are several ways. You can use [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) if you do not need any regexes:

```
perl -lwe 'print index("foobar", "bar");'
```

If you do need a regex, perhaps for some more complicated matches, you can use the predefined variable [`@-`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@-), which stores the position where your match begins:

```
perl -lwe '$str = "foobar"; if ($str =~ /bar/) { print $-[0] }'
```

However, I suggest you tell us what it is you are trying to do. Using string offsets is not the best perl tool in the box, and I suspect there are much better ways of solving your problem.

Comment: Well I am trying to print the data in a specific array position in a pipe delimited file, how can I achieve this?

Comment: @user1194777 That depends on your data. If it is proper CSV, you might consider using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV). If it is proper fixed width, consider `substr` or `unpack`. In order to be more specific, I'd need more information about your data, preferably a sample.

Comment: So I have 2 files with a key it like in 1st file  I have data as in following columns with value in it as...ID|Rating_Provider|Time|QualityRating              z6Y1kWFT99|S&P_LONG|20110120 12:00:00 AM|NR z6Y1kWFT99|MOODY'S_LONG|20101101 12:00:00 AM|NR
and in 2nd file I have data as in following columns in it as... ID|BBCMPSEC|QualityRating_S&P_LONG|Time_S&P_LONG|QualityRating_MOODY'S_LONG|Time_MOODY'S_LONG
Now finally I need to see the data as...ID|BBCMPSEC|QualityRating_S&P_LONG|Time_S&P_LONG|QualityRating_MOODY'S_LONG|Time_MOODY'S_LONG z6Y1kWFT99|xxx|NR|20110120 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: @user1194777 You should probably add that to your question instead, and format it so that it is possible to tell if its fixed width or csv.

Comment: Its a pipe delimited file                     ID|Rating_Provider|Time|QualityRating             z6Y1kWFT99|S&P_LONG|20110120 12:00:00 AM|NR z6Y1kWFT99|MOODY'S_LONG|20101101 12:00:00 AM|NR

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look at [pos](http://p3rl.org/pos)?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $str = 'foobarbaz';
$str =~ /bar/g;
print pos($str), "\n";
print substr( $str, pos($str) ), "\n";
pos($str) = pos($str) + 2;
print substr( $str, pos($str) ), "\n";
```